# Ubuntu / See restart history

Tags: ubuntu

Is there someplace in Ubuntu where I can look to see when the server has been restarted? Like a history, and not just the last restart.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [last](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last) command. It will show you when the server was rebooted.

Comment: I need more information then just the *last* reboot, and this is all it shows

Comment: The `last` command shows more then just the most recent reboot.  It shows all the reboots since the last time wtmp was log rotated.  If you have lots of logins, you will need to pass some options to see more details.